# Registering single Listener for Multiple queues. Is it possible?

Tags: java, mq

I am writing a module where I am going to receive data from multiple queues. I don't have to read the message..however just redirect them somewhere else. MY code looks something like this.

```
public Class MyQueueListener implement MessageListener {

protected List<IMQDetails> mqDetailsList;

public void onMessage(Message msg) {

        doSomething();
}

    public void init() {

        for(int i=0 ; i < mqDetailsList.size() ; i++){
            QueueSession session = mqDetailsList.get(i).createSession();
            QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(mqDetailsList.get(i).getQueue());
            receiver.setMessageListener(this);

    }

}
```

---

My MQ details list is an interface. The implementing class with create the session for me.

The tricky part ( I feel ) is that in for loop I am creating QueueRecieve object and registering the instance of the object (i.e the listener) to it.

So for eg: If i connect to 10  different queues, will my OnMessage trigger for all of them irrespective of the fact that message arrives on any of the queue ?

Pls Note: We don't have the queue infra with us to test it and cannot download ActiveMQ etc to mock the queues.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about the MessageListener or QueueReceiver types.  But regarding listeners in general: yes, you can register the same listener with more than one object that supports listeners.  You do have to be aware that the same listener could be called at the same time on different threads (unless the rest of the application's logic makes this impossible).  So if your listener object has instance variables, you need to be careful that two `onMessage` methods running on different threads coordinate how they access those variables.

Comment: Thanks ajb. Makes sense :-)